# Convert windows phone 7 proj to win mobile 6.5?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-phone-7, compatibility

Did someone try to convert a windows phone 7 project written in c# to an application that's working on a windows mobile 6.5 .

The question is: Are there some special libraries (for "painting the screen") that won't work with the win mobile CF ?

The only thing I know, that the application written in c# for win phone 7 is compiled in some strange (I don't remember now) file extensions, not in *.cab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more or less impossible. The programming model of Windows phone 7 is Silverlight (the extension is *.xap). The programming model of win mobile <= 6.5 is native code or .NET compact framework.

The only thing you can share between Windows phone 7 and Win mobile <= 6.5 is some code libraries at source code level, not compiled code. Code that might be possible to share is algorithmic code, not GUI code or code targeting specific libraries in the different platforms.

The only way to run a Windows phone 7 app on Win mobile <= 6.5 would be to write a Silverlight environment for Win mobile.

Comment: Server side logic is fine, but any phone stuff has to be Silverlight or XNA based as mentioned here.

Comment: If they are really serious, port moonlight http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight to Windows Mobile!